# How to avoid file:// protocol and show images using http://

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, http-protocols, file-uri

It seems we cannot show images on Google Chrome using [file:// protocol](https://superuser.com/questions/224500/display-local-images-in-chrome-using-file-protocol).

I think would be nice to have a way to load the file on a remote network such as `file://my-network-computer/my-folder/my-file.jpg` and render it as image on a asp.net page.

Is it possible to load bytes from a file on a network drive, then render its content as image on asp.net page?

Comment: Just to clarify: It's not just chrome that won't do that; all of the browsers worth their salt should stop it.

Answer (score 3):

You could write a handler that opens the file on the network using its UNC path and writes its contents to the response using [`Response.WriteFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.writefile.aspx):

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Handler" %>

using System.IO;

public class NetworkImageHandler : System.Web.IHttpHandler
{
  // Folder where all images are stored, process must have read access
  private const string NETWORK_SHARE = @"\\computer\share\";

  public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
  {
      string fileName = context.Request.QueryString["file"];
      // Check for null or empty fileName
      // Check that this is only a file name, and not 
      // something like "../../accounting/budget.xlsx"
      // Check that the file extension is valid

      string path = Path.Combine(NETWORK_SHARE, fileName);
      // Check if the file exists

      context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
      context.Response.WriteFile(path, true);
  }

  public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }
}
```

Then you set the image `src` to the handler url:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/NetworkImageHandler.ashx?file=file.jpg" />
```

Be very strict about checking the input, **don't create a handler that would allow someone to open just any file on your network**. Restrict access to a single folder, only give the worker process access to that folder and check for valid file extensions (e.g. jpg, jpeg, png, gif).

*This is a rather simple example, don't use it in production without testing.*

For alternative ways to write content to the response, and more example code, see:

- [Response.BinaryWrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.binarywrite.aspx)
- [Response.Transmit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.transmitfile.aspx)
- [Response.OutputStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.outputstream.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible.

You can transform the bytes to a base64 string and set the image src to be the base64 string.

Example:

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhDwAPAKECAAAAzMzM/////
wAAACwAAAAADwAPAAACIISPeQHsrZ5ModrLlN48CXF8m2iQ3YmmKqVlRtW4ML
wWACH+H09wdGltaXplZCBieSBVbGVhZCBTbWFydFNhdmVyIQAAOw=="
alt="Base64 encoded image" width="150" height="150"/>
```

And the way you convert the bytes to a base64 string is:

```
 base64String = System.Convert.ToBase64String(binaryData, 
                            0,
                            binaryData.Length);
```

Comment: Does that work for larger images. Don't you hit a url length limit after a few kB?

Comment: @CodeInChaos It does have some limitations, this Wikipedia Article (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) has a very thorough explanation